# How can I read and write the external file field in solr?

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am using External File field in solr for my frequently updated types of data. I had created a file `_external_<myfieldTypename`> in my Index directory. And my data is like :

```
4950 = 150.0
4951 = 65.0
4952 = 789.0
4953 = 786.0
4954 = 5.0
4955 = 21.0
```

Now I had created new field as:

`<fieldType name="<myfieldTypename>" class="solr.ExternalFileField" keyField="Name" defVal="1" indexed="false" stored="false" valType="float"/>`

`<field name="MyFieldName" type="<myfieldTypename>" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

My question is that how can I read data from my *external* file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Working+with+External+Files+and+Processes) :-

> Solr looks for the external file in the index directory under the name
>   of `external_<fieldname>` or `external_<fieldname>.*`

So in your case the external field file name should be MyFieldName.txt or external_MyFieldName.txt with the data.

> External fields are not searchable. They can be used only for function
>   queries or display.

Comment: It has been already created. but Is there any way or query that will be executed from Solr admin and we can see it whether that field contains data or not?

Comment: you should be able to get the data back in the response, so you can if the value exists or not.

Comment: I've already gone through that documentation and have done all steps but I dont know how to verify?

Comment: when you query Solr for the record q=id:something or q=*:* you should be able to receive the data back in the response.

Comment: Suppose,  id is 4950 and have mapped with value in external file. So when request like "Id:4950" in solr admin query browser, i didn't get any data from that field even didn't get that field.

Comment: http://<host>:<port>/solr/<core>/select?q=id:4950 ... should return the record. If it doesn't, the record does not exist.

Comment: I got all fields except external file field.

Comment: does the file abide to the naming convention ? and did you do an reindexing ??

Comment: Still not getting output after re indexing. Is there any problem in defining my field type? And field?

Comment: thats strange. Can you recheck if you have the file with the naming convention and case as specified in the answer and its in the index directory of your collection. You can check the logs to confirm its being loaded.

Comment: I agree with Jayendra's last comment. Based on the Documentation link provided in this answer, you do not have the name of the external file or fieldType defined properly.

Comment: Is external file name should be as external file field name or field type name? Please advice. Because some sites are saying different different names?

Comment: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-ALPHA/org/apache/solr/schema/ExternalFileField.html mentions it should be the field name.

Comment: Thanks jayendra. My fieldtype is "<fieldType name="customfile" class="solr.ExternalFileField" keyField="Id" defVal="0" stored="true" indexed="true"  valType="pfloat"/>" and field is "<field name="MostPopularProduct" type="customfile"  />" and got error... http://i48.tinypic.com/2pzcls6.png .... Am i doing wrong or what?

Comment: cant make out much from the error and the write method in the java file directly throws this exception. So the question is why is this method called. Did you clean up and reindex the complete data again ?

Comment: Yes We did reindex but no response found.

Comment: @Jayendra How to check into the logs whether the file / field is being loaded or not?

Comment: When I trying to request " http://localhost:8983/solr/core-live/select/?q=*%3A*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=100&indent=on&sort=mostpopularproduct%20desc " got another error.....http://i49.tinypic.com/25ktrhd.png

Comment: Can we use external field for ordering?

Comment: external fields can be used in function queries and sort can support function queries. Also you can try using the standalone field for sort should work seamlessly.

Answer (score 3):

`how can I read data from my external file?`

Asked the same question to solr-user group. (See [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/solr-user@lucene.apache.org/msg84637.html).) Yonik Seely's answer in that thread works fine for me in Solr 4.2.1. The syntax to use is:

`fl=*,field(external_file_field)`

You can also alias it, like Yonik says:

`fl=*,views:field(external_file_field)`